# Is this extension of Hoeffding's inequality known?

Tags: pr.probability, measure-concentration

**Question Overview:**

Is it already known that, when using Hoeffding's inequality to lower bound the mean of i.i.d. random variables, you can replace the upper bound on the random variables with the largest observed sample?

**Question Detail:**

Is the following result known?

Let $X_1,\dotsc,X_n$ be $n$ i.i.d. random variables where each $X_i \in [a,b]$. Then, for any $\delta \in (0,0.5]$:
$$
\Pr \left (\mathbf{E}\left [ X_1 \right ] > \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n X_i - (\max\{X_1,\dotsc,X_n\}-a)\sqrt{\frac{\ln(1/\delta)}{2n}} \right )\geq 1-\delta.
$$

Notice that, if using Hoeffding's inequality, $\max\{X_1,\dotsc,X_n\}$ would be replaced with $b$. For random variables with large possible upper bounds that are rarely realized, this could make a big difference.

Comment: Is the result known to *you*?  That is, are you saying you can prove it, or do you not know whether or not it is true?

Comment: It is true - it follows from [Anderson's 1969 concentration inequality](https://statistics.stanford.edu/sites/default/files/AND%20ONR%2001.pdf). I needed to put Anderson's bound into the form of Hoeffding's inequality for something I'm doing, and I got this result after loosening Anderson's bound a bit. I was surprised by this result and couldn't find it online. I'm curious whether this is known / if it's surprising to others / if I can just reference someone else to state this rather than having to include it as a claim that is unrelated to the topic of my paper (but which I need).

Comment: This does look interesting and somewhat surprising, and Anderson's paper seems very nice. Is your derivation of your inequality from Anderson's result available?

Comment: I've uploaded it [here](http://psthomas.com/temp/Hoeffding_Like_Inequality.pdf). I hesitate to call it a different inequality from Anderson's - it's really just putting his in a different form (which requires loosening it slightly).

Comment: Can you replace $a$ with the minimum?

Comment: @OriGurel-Gurevich Not in the lower bound in the original post. In the upper bound, $b$ remains but you can replace $a$ with the minimum (see the document I linked in my response to Iosif).

Comment: Since $b$ does not explicitly appear in the bound, does it follow that it holds for one-sidedly unbounded random variables?

Comment: @AryehKontorovich For continuous distributions, yes---we only require that $X_i \geq a$. I am not sure for non-continuous distributions though, because I am not familiar with the details of [Diouf and Dufour's argument](http://web.hec.ca/scse/articles/Diouf.pdf) (Proposition 2) for why Anderson's inequality extends to non-continuous random variables, and so I don't know if it causes the requirement that $b$ exists to return. I'll look into this after work today.

Comment: There's quite a bit of interest in concentration inequalities for unbounded (or semi-unboudned) random variables. See the related work section here, for example: http://jmlr.org/proceedings/papers/v32/kontorovicha14.html

Comment: @AryehKontorovich I've since checked - all of the steps do hold for one-sided random variables. An updated derivation with more details is [here](http://psthomas.com/temp/Hoeffding_Like_Inequality_v2.pdf).